# Segmentation Fault: Core Dumped

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   FILE *fp = ("Hello.txt","w");
   fprintf (fp, "\n Hello World");
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting this message while running this program

> "Segmentation fault(core dumped)".

It would be very helpful if i get an idea about why this happens and how to fix it. I am currently using
codeblocks in ubuntu. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `FILE *fp = ("Hello.txt","w");` -> `FILE *fp = fopen("Hello.txt","w");` Didn't your compiler show at least warnings?

Comment: Before using the fprintf() function, did you check if the file has been successfully created ==> fp != NULL ?

Comment: Yes, missed that :-)

Comment: @J.Piquard, given that state of his code, that check will actually pass.

Answer (score 0):

yes. as Michael walz commented. you missed fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   FILE *fp = fopen("Hello.txt","w");
   fprintf (fp, "\n Hello World");
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fopen in your code.
Also, to avoid other problems, always check the return value of fopen. It will be NULL if anything went wrong opening the file (e.g. out of space, wrong permissions)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("Hello.txt", "w");

    if (fp==NULL)
        return -1;

    fprintf (fp, "\n Hello World");
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
FILE *fp = ("Hello.txt","w");
```

is clearly erroneous from an intent point of view in that you appear to have missed the step of telling the compiler what actual function you want to call. What you almost certainly wanted to do was:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Hello.txt", "w");
```

Any decent compiler should have warned you about this such as with the `gcc` warning:

```
FILE *fp = ("Hello.txt","w");
           ^
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

and I often compile with the `-Werror` flag so as to have the compiler treat warnings as errors, to catch precisely this sort of thing.

---

You may actually be wondering why the compiler considers this just a warning but the truth is that it's perfectly valid code. The parentheses around an expression are valid which is why you can write either `x = 7` or `x = (7)`, or even `x = (((((7)))))`, and have it mean the same thing.

What remains then is just the expression *within* the parentheses, and this uses the C comma operator. Basically, the expression `a, b` evaluates `a` (discarding the result) then evaluates `b` and uses that as the result of the expression.

You can verify this behaviour with the following program, which outputs `w`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
   char *fp = ("Hello.txt", "w");
   puts (fp);
   return 0;
}
```

---

You may *think* you would have limited use for such a beast but I'll guarantee you use it far more often than you think, such as with:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 100; i++, j += 2)
    printf ("%d x 2 = %d\n", i, j);
```

In situations like that, it's fine to throw away the result of the sub-expressions since you're simply relying on the `++` side effect of evaluation.

---

In your case, the statement:

```
FILE *fp = ("Hello.txt","w");
```

will evaluate `"Hello.txt"` and use `"w"` to assign to `fp` (hence the incompatible pointer warning).

Then, when you attempt to *use* the address of `"w"` as if it was a valid `FILE` pointer, all bets are off.

---

And, as a side note, you should generally check the return value of all functions that can fail if such a failure may later affect your program. It's unwise to assume that `fopen` (or `malloc`, or a host of other functions) will always work. For `fopen`, it's a matter of ensuring the returned value is not `NULL`.